# UnManagedBean setter not called

Tags: jsf-1.2, trinidad

I have run in to  wierd issue where the setter of a property within my managedbean is not called.

I have 4 javabeans and out of which  two are managed bean and two are  POJO

`ManagedbeanA` has instance of `ManagedbeanB` which has a instance of `PojoA` object which is alist of `pojoB` rendered in a fragment included within my main jsp.

The list of `PojoB` objects are rendered as table and that table contains text boxes which can be edited by the user. The problem is that the when the user submits the form the setter of the property which hold the values of the textfield within the `PojoB` is never called.

i am referencing the list of pojoB objects as below within my JSF fragment included within my main JSP which has the submit button and the whole main page is sorrounded by the

```
<t:dataList id="tableEx1"
            binding="#{managedbeanA.ManagedBeanB.pojoA.htmlDataTableforPojoB}"
            value="#{managedbeanA.ManagedBeanB.pojoA.listofpojoB}"
            var="PojoB">
  <h:outputText id="sampletext" value="#{pojoB.sampleText}"/>
</t:datalist>
```

I am using trinidad components.

Comment: What are the errors you getting?

Comment: I assume that the typo in your `var` attribute (`PojoB` vs. `pojoB`) is only present in this post and not in your actual code?